# On the implicit relationship ${f(x) = e^{-1+x+f(x)}}$

Tags: calculus

I have a very simple question regarding the following implicitly defined function

$${f(x) = e^{-1+x+f(x)}}$$

if I wrote $y=-x$ would I then just get

$${f(y) = e^{-1-y+f(y)}}$$

It works for explicit functions but I'm not sure what exactly happens with the $f(x)$ (or $f(-x)$) in the power.

Answer (score 1):

After replacement, you have

$${f(-y) = e^{-1-y+f(-y)}},$$

which you can rewrite

$${g(y) = e^{-1-y+g(y)}},$$

by defining $g(y):=f(-y)$.

---

Note that you can explicitize with

$$-f(x)e^{-f(x)}=-e^{-1+x}$$ so that by the Lambert function

$$-f(x)=W(-e^{-1+x}).$$

Answer (score 1):

Once more, the beautiful [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) appears here.

If $${f(x) = e^{-1+x+f(x)}}$$ then $$f(x)=-W\left(-e^{x-1}\right)$$